# Can't remove URL on ALL profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks

There is a bug removing URL from the profile.

1. Website link has some URL.
2. Remove URL (empty field).
3. "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button pressed.

**Observed result:** Empty URL only on the current SE site.

---

**Expected result:** Empty URL on all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: from which site profile are you removing URL? SO or TeX - LaTeX? Try removing from SO with "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities"

Comment: @HackerKarma I tried multiple times for few days for about 10 sites from my profile. Complete remove of URL isn't saved cross-site (instead of it's change to some other URL).

Comment: Ok... this is interesting... what does it shows in the 'Last sync' on your network profile? On this page: http://stackexchange.com/users/1019257/m0nhawk

Comment: "Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow). Last sync 17s ago." I have an idea that this is because the empty URL is somehow consider incorrect and thus not syncing.

Comment: I have Empty URL on my SO Profile and it does not seems to have issue... I see your other profiles are showing Google.com URL. Did you added that?

Comment: Yes, I have added this as a test.

Comment: I think syncing Empty URL from your SO profile should have worked... could it be Cache issue?

Comment: First time I noticed this a week ago (on SO)... I may try again for a day or two.

Comment: @m0nhawk only changes/diff vs the current values are propagated to the entire network... so if you have an empty string initially and don't change it, and then save _changes_ to all sites, you won't have any _changes_ to save.

Comment: That's not what the OP is saying @m0sa; they have a URL on all sites, remove it on one of the sites and copy to all other sites, but the change doesn't take effect. It sounds like an equality check isn't taking nulls into account... (Assuming I'm reading the question correctly)

Comment: OP is saying: When the URL field _is_ empty, and "Save and copy _changes_ to all Stack Exchange communities" button pressed... I'm saying he has to _change_ it from something to empty in order for the _change_ to propagate.

Comment: @m0sa I'm actually, _changing_ it from something to empty and than save. I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: ah, thanks for clarifying, Iooking

Answer (score 5):

There was a bug in how the new profile handles the website url. The old profile had a single custom url, and that was the one that was being displayed in that field.

A fix is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.9.28.3723` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.28.2851` on sites).